# Does a plain latte have chocolate in it?

Tags: chocolate, espresso

I cannot eat chocolate but would like to drink a latte.  Is there any chocolate in a regular latte?  I know you can get a chocolate latte, but need to know if a plain latte has chocolate in it.

Comment: A "chocolate latte" would be called a mocha.  There are many lovely charts out there which nicely depict the differences between espresso drinks, like this one: http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0319/8489/files/espresso-recipe-guide-966x1224.png?1086

Answer (score 4):

No, it does not. A latte is espresso with steamed milk and a thin layer of steamed milk foam on top. Assuming your barista knows what he is doing, you'd have to specially ask to get chocolate in a latte, and then it would be called a mocha (in the US).

Comment: And foam!  Foam is important.

Comment: @logophobe Sigh...Ok, edited to include.

Comment: Not a big deal, you nailed the substance of the question.  I've just been criticized before for forgetting foam.  I'm not a barista, just a pedant.

Comment: I'm just giving you crap :)

Comment: It's got a bit of foam on the top unless it's a wet latte, which is milk with no foam.